# Calculating $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac1x \int_{0}^{x}f(y)dy$ when $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was trying the following problem which is :

> Let $f \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function such that $$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=a .$$ Then $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac1x \int_{0}^{x}f(y)dy $$ is which of the following:
>
> $(A)1 \,\,(B)a \,\,\,(C)-1 \,\,\,(D)$ does not exist

*My Attempt*:  WLOG,I take $f(x)=a+bx$ ,then I see option (B) is the correct choice. Am I right? Is there any better alternative way to tackle the problem?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Concerning your attempt: that is certainly not WLOG.  It is with complete loss of generality when you assume that $f$ has the form $f(x) = a+bx$.  What about $f(x) = a + \sin x$?

Comment: If you take $f(x) = a+bx$, you can't say "WLOG", because nobody said that your function is differentiable, even less $C^1$; you *are* losing generality. Consider a counterexample $f(x) = a+\sqrt x$.

Comment: thanks a lot @AntonioVargas sir for pointing out the mistake in my argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta > 0$ so that $|x| < \delta\implies |f(x) - a| < \epsilon$.  Then if $x < \delta$,
$$\left|{1\over x}\int_0^x f(t)\, dt - a\right| \le  \frac {1}{|x|}
\int_0^x |f(t) - a| \, dt \le \epsilon.$$
Consequently, the limit is $a$.

Comment: Thanks for catching the |.| I missed, TZakrevskiy.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You can use L'hopital's rule. Let

> $$ F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(y) dy $$

and consider the limit

> $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)}{x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

1. For each interval $[0,x]$, define
   $$
   M_x = \sup \{f(y) : y \in [0,x]\} \text{ and } m_x = \inf\{f(y) : y\in [0,x]\}
   $$
   Then
   $$
   m_x \leq \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(y)dy \leq M_x
   $$
   Hence, by intermediate value theorem, there is a point $c_x \in [0,x]$ such that
   $$
   \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(y)dy = f(c_x)
   $$
   Now, $0 \leq c_x \leq x$ for all $x$, and the fact that $f$ is continuous, implies that
   $$
   \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(y)dy = \lim_{x\to 0} f(c_x) = a
   $$

For the rest, you are on the right track, so explain what you tried a little more, and someone here can complete your proof.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, $\int_0^xf(y)dy$ is differentiable. Thus using L'Hospital's rule we get $f(0)$ as the limit.

Comment: @user40615 : To prove the fundamental theorem of calculus, one usually uses the above property (the mean-value theorem for integrals)

Comment: Agree, but it is asked ''what is the limit''.

Comment: @user40615 : When one asks a question in mathematics, one usually expects justification for the answer.

Comment: Mean ''cant we use the FTC?''It is known fact why do we need prove once again?